# Simple voting system in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create simple upvote system for posts. I added column to the model and this is how my posts_controller looks now:

```
  def upvote
    @upvote = @post.upvote + 1
  end
```

Don't know how to  make it work in the views? I want to make link which adds +1 to upvote.
Don't know also how to handle routes.

Comment: You'll probably want to use something like [`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) with the `remote: true` option in the view. An Ajax request will be made to your controller action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take two approaches, normal post html verb or ajax. The ajax way would look something like:

```
# view
link_to 'Upvote this thing!', upvote_post_path(post), remote: true

# routes
resources :posts do
  member do
    post :upvote
  end
end

# controller
def upvote
  @post.update_attributes(upvote: @post.upvote + 1)
  ... do some ajax-y rendering here, like highlighting or replacing html
end
```

The other way would work similarly, except you wouldn't have remote: true on the link_to and you would likely have upvote look something more like:

```
def upvote
  @post.update_attributes(upvote: @post.upvote + 1)
  redirect_to show_post_path(@post)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG-kCSx0taU

Video I used to implement mine. If you need to display the total number of votes, then just run `vote.count` or `vote.size`.

Comment: <%= post.upvote.to_s %> to show total upvotes but i want to make it a link which adds +1.

Comment: Right. Check that video out.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is usually better to include the specifics of the answer in the body of the post. Links can become broken and/or content deleted, which leaves only an insubstantial answer. Plus, not everyone has the freedom or immediate capability of searching through a 20 minute video.